# We use char[] for sensitive data in java, what about in Kotlin? Is CharArray okay?

Tags: java, security, kotlin

thanks in advance.  We all know why we should use `char[]` instead of `String` for sensitive data such as password in Java. I'm just wondering about that same situation in Kotlin.

The [document](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-array/index.html) says "When targeting the JVM, instances of this class (meaning `CharArray`) are represented as `char[]`".  Does it mean using `CharArray` in Kotlin will have the same benefit (in terms of security) as using `char[]` in Java?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. If you look at the bytecode, usages of `CharArray` are literally compiled to `char[]`, so it will have the exact same security benefits vs using a `String`.

If you're in IntelliJ, you can invoke the `Show Kotlin Bytecode` action and check this sort of thing yourself (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd> or <kbd>⌘⇧A</kbd> to search for actions, or you can find it under `Tools -> Kotlin`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I use Android Studio, and can also find the "`Show Kotlin Bytecode`" option under menu `Tools->Kotlin`, will definitely give it a try.